# AppleID syncing issue

Tags: macbook-pro

I deleted files from my Mac, but at the same time same files from another Mac with the same AppleID got deleted too. Also I got the backup for the files. But I want to change this for future. How to do it?

Also if I change the AppleID of my Mac then will the files and all data get erased on the other Mac too (there the AppleID will remain as the old one) as a result?

Comment: Usually its best to only answer **one** question at a time and not multiple questions at once. I suggest you rephrase this post and ask a new question for the second part

Answer (score 2):

iCloud is a sync solution, not a backup solution. Deleting from one device deletes from all, by design.

If you used two separate IDs, they would not sync at all. Each would be completely independent.

If you don't want syncing, you'd be best to disable it rather than attempt to use two separate IDs.
System Prefs > iCloud > iCloud Drive > Options…
Disable everything except essentials like Contacts etc.

As it's a structure I've never used, precisely because I don't want the same data on all machines, I don't know what warnings you will get if you disable. Make sure at least one machine keeps the original data & make sure Time Machine is up to date.

Comment: So if i remove my apple id from one device...Will it change/delete anything from the other device at all?

Comment: I'm not so sure how simple it would be to 'remove' an AppleID from a device. I've never tried it. You'd have to sign out of everything, that would not in itself delete synced data. The OS & all App Store apps, would still belong to the original ID unless you wiped the Mac & set up as a new machine, but then any purchased apps would need to be re-purchased.